# making a tree crack and creak and falling with sound synthesis

Tags: sound-design, synthesis

I'm have a good grasp of basic synthesis but need to make some sounds synthetically quite quickly for a project, and am not sure where to start

It is a the cracking and creaking as a tree or large wooden object falls..

Any advice appreciated!

PTG

Comment: Why does it need to be synthesized? Can't you just go out and record some actual source?

Comment: Hi Jay. I'm trying to add some modernity to a record that is pretty much all live instruments. The thinking is that by a synthesizing all the effects that go with the video, it will add something 'stylised' and different. I had thought of taking samples and using digital filtering, vocoding and/or other manipulation. that would probably be a lot easier but not the same.

Comment: Sounds like a challenge - good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I used Odin 2 (a free VST) and used the Drum sounds there (specifically hihat and snare) of which I changed the lowpass filter.

Also I used an equalizer to add mid frequencies

Then I added a reverb and limiter
Also I added a noice and filtered it so one can hear the mids at the beginning, the lows in the middle and the highs at the end.

here is a short video of it:

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:

Creating a synthesised rim shot-like sound is easy, now play with pitch and this "exponential rhythm" idea/technique. You should be on the good way.

Comment: Oh awesome!! that's a great idea... Thank you!